# Unknown not assignable to type: Typescript Error in Redux Observable

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-observable

I get the following error in Redux Observable.
How would I solve this issue?

Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<ITodo[], Action<{ params: { url: string; }; } & { result: { todos: ITodo[]; }; }>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, Action<{ params: { url: string; }; } & { result: { todos: ITodo[]; }; }>>'.
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ITodo[]'.ts(2345)

```
export interface ITodo {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

interface IPayloadAction extends Action {
  type: string;
  payload?: any;
}

const todoFetchEpic: Epic<IPayloadAction> = (actions$) =>
  actions$.pipe(
    ofType(todoActions.fetch.started.type),
    mergeMap((action: IPayloadAction) =>
      concat(
        of(todoActions.loading({ isLoading: true })),
        ajax.getJSON(action.payload.url).pipe(
          map((todos: ITodo[]) =>
            todoActions.fetch.done({
              params: action.payload.url,
              result: {todos}
            })
          ),
          catchError((_) =>
            of(
              todoActions.fetch.failed({
                params: action.payload.url,
                error: { hasError: true },
              })
            )
          )
        ),
        of(todoActions.loading({ isLoading: false }))
      )
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the `AjaxCreationMethod` interface:

```
export interface AjaxCreationMethod {
    // ... other methods ...
    getJSON<T>(url: string, headers?: Object): Observable<T>;
}
```

You can see that for `getJSON` you can specify generic type for the response.
Without it, the compiler has no clue on the shape of data returned, and assumes `unknown`.

Change your code as follows:

```
ajax.getJSON<ITodo[]>(action.payload.url)
```